# React update s stateless component from another compoent

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function App() { return(<div><customButton/><customTable/></div>) }
export default function customButton() { return(<div><button>update</button></div>) }
```

Since the app is the parent component and button and table are child components. I know this is not the best practice but how do I update(re-render) table component from the button component?

Comment: Easy way is create a state and a function to change this state in parent component, then pass the function into children component as a children's prop and execute function inside children component

Comment: See [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: @iamjcc check this solution which i created for your help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618401/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to have some shared state at the closest ancestor. In the example below, I create a `value` state variable in `App` and pass it to the `customTable` element. I have a `setValue` setter that is passed to `customButton`. When the button is clicked, the `value` is updated and passed to `customTable`, causing the table to re-render with that new value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return(
    <div>
      <customButton setValue={setValue} />
      <customTable value={value} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default function customButton({ setValue }) {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(v => v + 1)}>update</button>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing that. But the button only allow it to update once. How do update whenever I clicked?

Comment: Well, the state can be whatever you want it to be. I’ll update it to just keep incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Sample application using custom table and custom button.

```
function CustomButton(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.addClick}>{props.children}</button>
}
function CustomTable({ table }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {table.map((item, i) => (
          <tr key={i.toString()}>
            <td>{i.toString()}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')
  const [table, setTable] = React.useState([
    { name: "John" },
    { name: "Bukky" },
    { name: "Behem" }
  ]);
  const handleInput = e=>{
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const addClick = e => {
    const update = [...table, { name: input }];
    setTable(update);
    setInput('')
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={input} onChange={handleInput}/>
      <CustomButton addClick={addClick}>Click to Add</CustomButton>
      <CustomTable table={table} />
    </div>
  );
}
```